How to avoid circular dependencies in Ada?
I have two packages called Passenger and Booking. They have a one to many relationship. I encountered a circular dependency error when I tried to do with in both of their files. I then tried limited with Passenger and made the Booking record store Passenger as an access type.
package body Bookings is

   procedure initialize_booking (b : in out Booking; flight : Unbounded_String; booker : Passengers.Passenger) is
   begin
      b.ID := nextID;
      b.seat := nextSeat;
      b.flight := flight;
      b.booker := access booker;

      nextID := nextID + 1;
   end initialize_booking;

The above procedure is an example of how I am trying to store the access type in the booking record. I get a "missing operand" error.
Can someone please explain where I am going wrong?
An explanation on how to do a many-many or how I'd do it for the reverse way where I use a vector with access types of Booking stored in Passenger would be greatly appreciated too.
How can I use the access typed variable to access the object within and call its methods too?
Thanks for helping.

"booker := access booker;" is almost definitely wrong. You sure it's not supposed to be booker'Access ?

If Ada containers are permitted, consider a Vector for instances of each entity and a Map for the relationship, e.g. key Passenger to a Vector of Bookings made by that Passenger.

It would be nice if you could give us a simplified example that fully compiles minus the error you are getting.  Then we could maybe give you some more solidified answers on how to deal with it.  We don't need all your code, just some skeleton of some of it that highlights the issue and that compiles (or would if a specific line was removed, annotating that line).

Access types should be used only as a last resort. The way to avoid circular dependencies for things like this is either child pkgs or a third pkg to represent the passenger => bookings relationship. With child pkgs you'd have something like
package Passengers is
   type ID is private;

   Invalid : constant ID;
private -- Passengers
   type ID is record
      Value : Natural := 0;
   end record;

   Invalid : constant ID := (Value => 0);
end Passengers;

with Passengers;
package Bookings is
   type ID is private;

   Invalid : constant ID;

   type Info is record
      Passenger : Passengers.ID;
      ...
   end record;

   function Booking_Info (Booking : in ID) return Info with
      Pre => Booking /= Invalid;

   -- Operations on bookings here
private -- Bookings
   type ID is record
      Value : Natural := 0;
   end record;

   Invalid : constant ID := (Value => 0);
end Bookings;

with Bookings;
package Passengers.Operations is
   type Info is record
      -- Might contain a set of booking IDs
   end record;

   function Passenger_Info (Passenger : in ID) return Info with
      Pre => Passenger /= Invalid;

    -- Operations on passengers here
end Passengers.Operations;

with Passengers.Operations;
package body Bookings is
   ...
end Bookings;

The Info types might need to be private, too. Breaking out the passenger operations into a child package allows Passengers to be independent of Bookings, Bookings to with Passengers, and Passengers.Operations to with Bookings.
The 3rd-pkg way has Bookings and Passengers being completely independent, and the 3rd pkg provides a map from Passengers.ID to a set of Bookings.ID. It's simpler and so may be preferable.
